# Natural way to ask what project/work someone has been doing lately

Tags: phrase-requests

What is a natural way or ways to ask about what project(s) or work someone is doing lately at a job? In English I'd say:

> So what project have you been working on lately?
>
> So what have you been working on lately?

I am not sure if these translate well literally or there is some other expression I should use.

> 最近、どんなプロジェクトをしていますか？
>
> 最近、何の仕事をしていますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 最近、何の仕事をしていますか

*might* sound as if you have no idea on his recent job, a shoemaker or a preacher.  Of course that shouldn't cause any confusions in a real world, but someone like me may find it a good opportunity to crack a joke, "C'mon, did anybody tell you I was fired?  Hell no!  I'm still working at XYZ Corp!"

I prefer

> 最近、どんなプロジェクトをしていますか

because it's both natural and the least ambiguous.  But wait... プロジェクトをしている might slightly sound unnatural.  Its more casual form

> 最近、どんなプロジェクトをやってるんですか？

is perfectly OK, but for some reason, プロジェクトをしています is not perfect.  Perhaps because, verbs like "する" "やる" are not genuinely polite, so their polite forms don't perfectly make sense. Well, I guess 90% of native Japanese speakers just accept either ways :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can just say something like:

> 最近仕事は何をしてる？
>
> 最近仕事の調子はどう？

You can of course modify it to be as polite as you want. Those are the two most common expressions I hear from my Japanese friends when we talk. Really, I hear this like all the time.